# How to inverse this matrix?

Tags: matrices

A long time ago I used to do it very fast and easily [A long time ago].

I would like to refresh my memory on what are the methods, steps to do in order to calculate an inverse of a matrix?

Let say I have this matrix as an example:

$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
        2      & 1      & \cdots & \cdots & 1 \\
        1      & 2      & \ddots      & \cdots & 1  \\
        1      & 1      & 2      & 1      & \vdots   \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
        1      & 1      & 1      & 1      & 2      
        \end{bmatrix}.$$

Or:
$$A=\left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
   2\\
    & 2 & & \huge1\\
    & & \ddots\\
    & \huge1 & & 2\\
    & & & & 2
 \end{array}
\right].$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is $ E + I $ where $E$ is the matrix of all $1$'s.  Now $E^2 = n E$ where the matrix is $ n \times n $, so any polynomial in $E$ will be of the form $a E + b I$.  If you try $(a E + b I) (E + I) = I$, you are led to the equations $n a + a + b = 0$ and $b = 1$, so $a = -1/(1+n) $.  That is, the inverse is
$(-1/(1+n)) E + I $.